# how to set an animation on image in bootstrap when mouse hover

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, css-animations, bootstrap-5

I want to set an animation on a image in my website when mouse over the image. but I do not want to use CSS. Is there any bootstrap class to animate an item directly?

Comment: Please share what you want to archive? which sort of animation? Currently the question is unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you want to accomplish it.

Is Bootstrap capable of adding animations to the elements? No

Boostrap is just a UI library with some premade components to help you build websites faster with consistency.

Are there any simple ways of accomplishing this? Yes

Method 1: Using plain CSS

```
.my-image:hover {
   /* Your custom animation here */
}
```

Method 2: Using JavaScript

```
yourElement.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
     e.target.classList.add("your CSS class");
});
```

and to remove the animation

```
yourElement.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
     e.target.classList.remove("your CSS class");
});
```

example of a class that will be added

```css
.rotate-js {
   /* Your custom animation here */
}
```

Good docs to consider reading:

MDN mouseover event: [mouseover, mouseenter, events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event)

W3SCHOOLS mouseover event: [onmouseover Event](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi-_a2148_3AhXiz4UKHWz5B-kQFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fevent_onmouseover.asp&usg=AOvVaw0HwCsLWfGxQ_akzpZOjf9B)

MDN mouseleave event: [mouseleave event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event)

**Note:** There are some libraries that will help you implement heavy/advanced animations like GSAP, and anime.js, give them a shot if you're interested.